# Is finger wagging considered offensive in a Canadian court?

Tags: canada, rules-of-court

It seems readily apparent to me that finger wagging is a bullying tactic used to establish social dominance by infantilizing the audience and elevating the perpetrator to a perceived position of authority.

However, would one reasonably expect that if an attorney were in the habit of wagging their finger at the jury or at witnesses while addressing them, the judge would intervene and instruct them to stop, or is this sort of thing generally tolerated?

Comment: What might be "readily apparent" to one person is highly subjective. The way it is perceived is also completely dependent on subtleties in the manner of execution. Asking a question of law concerning body language or other non-verbal mannerisms is probably the reason you are getting downvoted. (FWIW, i didn't vote either way...)

Comment: Is asking about rules of court room decorum off topic?  They will always have some subjectivity.  I figured the downvote was the person who inspired the question came across it ;) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Canadian court (and in most common law legal systems), the judge has what is sometimes called "direct [contempt of court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contempt_of_court) authority." This is a legacy of the ancient situation when judges were stand-ins for aristocrats or monarchs who were transitioning out of actively exercising judicial power in the pre-democratic era.

This means that the court can summarily fine or incarcerate someone on the spot, without a trial, for conduct that would otherwise be considered rude, but not a criminal offense. British Columbia, however, has abrogated this authority. As Wikipedia [explains the situation in Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contempt_of_court) which varies from court to court:

> *Common law offense*
>
> In Canada, contempt of court is an exception to the general principle
> that all criminal offences are set out in the federal Criminal Code.
> Contempt of court and contempt of Parliament are the only remaining
> common law offences in Canada.[12]
>
> Contempt of court includes the following behaviors:
>
> - Failing to maintain a respectful attitude, failing to remain silent or failing to refrain from showing approval or disapproval of the
>   proceeding
> - Refusing or neglecting to obey a subpoena
> - Willfully disobeying a process or order of the court
> - Interfering with the orderly administration of justice or impairing the authority or dignity of the court
> - An officer of the court failing to perform his or her duties
> - A sheriff or bailiff not executing a writ of the court forthwith or not making a return thereof
>
> *Canadian Federal courts*
>
> This section applies only to the Federal Court of Appeal and Federal
> Court.
>
> Under Federal Court Rules, Rules 466, and Rule 467 a person who is
> accused of Contempt needs to be first served with a contempt order and
> then appear in court to answer the charges. Convictions can only be
> made when proof beyond a reasonable doubt is achieved.
>
> If it is a matter of urgency or the contempt was done in front of a
> judge, that person can be punished immediately. Punishment can range
> from the person being imprisoned for a period of less than five years
> or until the person complies with the order or fine.
>
> *Tax Court of Canada*
>
> Under Tax Court of Canada Rules of Tax Court of Canada Act, a person
> who is found to be in contempt may be imprisoned for a period of less
> than two years or fined. Similar procedures for serving an order first
> is also used at the Tax Court.
>
> *Provincial courts*
>
> Different procedures exist for different provincial courts. **For
> example, in British Columbia, a justice of the peace can only issue a
> summons to an offender for contempt, which will be dealt with by a
> judge, even if the offence was done in the face of the justice.**

Usually, a judge would admonish (i.e. "warn" and "scold") a person in the courtroom not to engage in this kind of conduct before immediately imposing direct contempt of court sanctions, with the subtext (particularly in the context of an attorney) that this behavior is not acceptable if it is in a gray area like "finger wagging."

Of course, in addition to the contempt of court power, most proceedings in Canada are bench trials, and a lawyer who is deaf to what irritates a judge in a manner that the judge is consciously aware of is unlikely to be very successful in securing favorable results from that judge.

*Quebec Is Likely To Differ*

The way that this plays out may be different in Quebec (I don't know personally, having never been in a court proceeding in Quebec), because its courts are based upon French civil law system practice, despite creeping common law influence from Canada's other provinces.

In the French courts, judges were historically bureaucrats, not direct stand ins for a king or aristocrat. Also, any taint of royalist vestiges were purged from their system as an anti-monarchist political imperative during and in the wake of the French Revolution. So, in France, judges do not have contempt of court power and instead, much like local government councils now, relied on law enforcement officers to invoke criminal laws against disorderly conduct and disrupting meetings to enforce decorum, rather than relying on their own contempt of court power.

Many French courts are also more like offices or conference rooms, and less like common law courtrooms, which influences the character of those proceedings.

My hypothesis may be wrong, however. The [pertinent portions of the Code of Civil Procedure in Quebec](https://www.legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/document/cs/C-25?&target=#:%7E:text=Any%20person%20who%20contravenes%20article,80%2C%20a.) state:

> 14. Persons present at sittings of the courts must maintain a respectful attitude, remain silent and refrain from showing their
>     approval or disapproval of the proceedings.
>
> This provision must be observed wherever the judge carries out his
> official functions.
>
> 1965 (1st sess.), c. 80, a. 14.
>
> 15. Any person who contravenes article 14, or who does not obey at once the orders of the judge or the officers under his authority, is
>     guilty of contempt of court.
>
> If the offender is an officer of justice, the court may suspend him
> from his functions.
>
> 1965 (1st sess.), c. 80, a. 15; 1975, c. 83, s. 3; 1995, c. 41, s. 17.

But, again, since trials in Quebec are generally bench trials, a lawyer who is deaf to conduct that irritates a judge or seems unfair to a judge, and who ignores a judge's admonitions to refrain from certain conduct, is likely to be less successful on the merits.

> is this sort of thing generally tolerated?

Different judges run their courtrooms differently and some judges are more sensitive to conduct like "finger wagging" than others.

Judges have broad discretion with respect to how they maintain decorum in their courtrooms. Different judges interpret the meaning of this kind of conduct differently and assign different weights to it.

In the same vein, some judges are very uptight about insisting that people be referred to by attorneys and parties by their surnames with an honorific (like Mr., Ms., Dr., etc.), while other judges barely notice if people are referred to on a first name basis in court.

Likewise, some judges care a lot about people standing up when the judge enters and not sitting down until verbally given permission to do so, while others don't find it to be disrespectful to sit down before being given permission to do so.

Norms also differ from place to place (even within Canada) and in different time periods.

For example, it used to be considered disrespectful in the early 20th century and earlier for a woman to come into court wearing a pants-suit, but this is no longer the case. But using misgendered pronouns, which is now considered very disrespectful, wasn't an issue that even came up until the 21st century or the final years of the 20th century.